# Power BI - does it cache OData source meta data?

Tags: odata, powerbi

I'm using Power BI against an OData V4 source I'm currently developing so the data source metadata is changing regularly.  I've noticed that I've been bitten a few times by Power BI 'remembering' property names that no longer exist.

When I look at the data source metadata via a browser against the OData service itself, I see all the proper properties and navigation properties.  But in Power BI, when I specify the same OData service resource (via 'Get Data'), pick an entity, when it goes into Power BI query editor it's referencing 'old' properties that no longer exist - hence Power BI blows up.

So it looks like the old metadata is being held on somehow.  Is there anyway to reset what appears to be cached metadata?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Power PI Desktop.  Sorry for the confusion.  I turns out you need to go into 'Options and Settings' -> 'Data Source Settings', then delete all the OData URLS.  That seemed to work.

'Refresh Preview' just reloads the data, not the metadata, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to Power BI Desktop (not the Power BI web service)?

In the Edit Queries window, the Refresh Preview button should refresh the cached metadata.